# Nested if formula in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, if-statement

I am trying to perform a nested if (together with AND & OR function) in pandas, I have the following two data frame

```
dF1
TR_ID  C_ID  Code  Check1 Check2
1      101   P1     N       Y
2      102   P2     Y       Y
3      103   P3     N       Y
4      104   P4     Y       N
5      105   P5     N       N
6      106   P6     Y       Y
7      107   P7     N       N
8      108   P8     N       N
9      109   P9     Y       Y
10     110   P10    Y       N

dF2
C_ID  CC
101   A1
102   A2
103   A3
104   A4
105   A5
106   A6
107   A7
108   A8
109   A9
110   A10
```

I am trying to create a new column 'Result' in `Df1` using the below excel formula, I am fairly new to coding in Pandas Python,

Excel Formula =

```
IF(AND(OR($D2="P2",$D2="P4",$D2="P6",$D2="P9"),$E2="Y",$F2="Y"),"A11",VLOOKUP($C2,$J$2:$K$11,2,0))'
```

The resulting data frame should look like this

```
TR_ID  C_ID  Code  Check1 Check2  RESULT
1      101   P1     N       Y        A1
2      102   P2     Y       Y        A11
3      103   P3     N       Y        A3
4      104   P4     Y       N        A4
5      105   P5     N       N        A5
6      106   P6     Y       Y        A11
7      107   P7     N       N        A7
8      108   P8     N       N        A8
9      109   P9     Y       Y        A11
10     110   P10    Y       N        A10
```

I am trying this code in python `df1['CC'] = df1['Code'].apply(lambda x: 'A11' if x in ('P2','P4','P6','P9') else 'N')`

But I sm unable to incorporate the check1 & Check2 criteria and also else `vlookup` is not working.

any suggestion is greatly appreciated

Comment: kindly explain more what check 1 and 2 does. make it a bit clearer what the conditions are, and assume that the respondent is a noob when it comes to excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
# This is the first part of your IF statement
cond = (
    df1['Code'].isin(['P2', 'P4', 'P6', 'P9'])
        & df1['Check1'].eq('Y')
        & df1['Check2'].eq('Y')
)

# And the VLOOKUP
# (but don't name your dataframe `vlookup` in production code please
vlookup = df1[['C_ID']].merge(df2, on='C_ID')

# Combining the two
df1['RESULT'] = np.where(cond, 'All', vlookup['CC'])
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Excel that does not treat worksheets or cell ranges as data set objects, Pandas allows you to interact with data with named columns and attributes.

Therefore, consider using [**`DataFrame.merge`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) followed by a conditional logic such as [**`Series.where`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) calculation similar to `IF` formula. Also, `~` operator negates the logic condition.

```
p_list = ['P2', 'P4', 'P6', 'P9']

final_df = dF1.merge(dF2, on = "C_ID")

final_df['Result'] = final_df['CC'].where(~((final_df['Code'].isin(p_list))
                                             & (final_df['Check1'] == 'Y')
                                             & (final_df['Check2'] == 'Y')
                                             ), 'A11')

print(final_df)
#    TR_ID  C_ID Code Check1 Check2   CC Result
# 0      1   101   P1      N      Y   A1     A1
# 1      2   102   P2      Y      Y   A2    A11
# 2      3   103   P3      N      Y   A3     A3
# 3      4   104   P4      Y      N   A4     A4
# 4      5   105   P5      N      N   A5     A5
# 5      6   106   P6      Y      Y   A6    A11
# 6      7   107   P7      N      N   A7     A7
# 7      8   108   P8      N      N   A8     A8
# 8      9   109   P9      Y      Y   A9    A11
# 9     10   110  P10      Y      N  A10    A10
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/02a3f84d-b513-46db-a1e0-dea43b3eafce/?m=Saved%20fiddle)</kbd> *(click Run at top)*

Comment: Thank you so much, this makes more sense